# Windows phone 8 (toolkit) pushpins jumps/flickers

Tags: c#, binding, dictionary, windows-phone-8, pushpin

```cs
        <maps:Map x:Name="map">
            <maptk:MapExtensions.Children>
                <maptk:MapItemsControl Name="pushpinItems">
                    <maptk:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <maptk:Pushpin GeoCoordinate="{Binding geoCoordinateLocation}" Content="{Binding name}" PositionOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </maptk:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </maptk:MapItemsControl>
            </maptk:MapExtensions.Children>
        </maps:Map> 

    ...

    ObservableCollection<PinItem> pinsCollection = new ObservableCollection<PinItem>();


    private async void updateMap()
    {

        WebApiWorker webApi = new WebApiWorker();
        var responce = await webApi.GetAllPins();

        this.pinsCollection.Clear();

        foreach (PinItem pin in responce.array)
        {
            this.pinsCollection.Add(busActivity.MonitoredVehicleJourney);

        }

    }
```

I call my updateMap() method every 5 sec to get the updated pin locations from web service. When the pushpins are updated, they jump like 5 mm on screen.

If i set pushpin PositionOrigin="0,0" then pins are not jumping/flickering any more but they are little sifted as I have ellipse pushpins.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I've used custom `ControlTemplate` to resolve this issue:

```c#
<ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:Pushpin" x:Key="PinTemplate">
    <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="0,-60,0,0">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Grid Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    MinHeight="31" 
                    MinWidth="29">
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Presenter"
                    Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}"
                    FlowDirection="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=FlowDirection}" 
                    Margin="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
            <Polygon Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}" 
                Points="0,0 29,0 0,29" 
                Width="29" 
                Height="29" 
                Margin="0,-1,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then I've created Pushpins from my code like this:

```c#
var pp = new Pushpin
{
    Background = cObject.Bcolor,
    GeoCoordinate = cObject.Coordinate,
    Content = ppIc.Convert(cObject.Name, typeof (BitmapImage), null, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture),
    DataContext = cObject,
    Template = this.Resources["PinTemplate"] as ControlTemplate
};
pp.Tap += UIElement_OnTap;

var overlay = new MapOverlay
{
    Content = pp,
    GeoCoordinate = pp.GeoCoordinate
};
_pushpinLayer.Add(overlay);
```

The key here is to set a proper margin on root-level `Grid` of pushpin's template so it moves all elements higher and you don't have to set `PositionOrigin="0,1"`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found some workaround on 3d party site:

> I found a Workaround. Before I clear the PushPin-Collection - which leads to those jumping PushPins - I create a Bitmap of the Map and Show it above the map. Once the collection is updated I again hide the Bitmap-Map. This works for the Moment, but takes more resources than necessary:

```
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap((int)_map.ActualWidth,(int)_map.ActualHeight);
    bmp.Render(_map, new System.Windows.Media.TranslateTransform());
    bmp.Invalidate();
    MapImage = bmp;
    MapImageVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

But it looks not good enough :(